# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/users"}, missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

method in my my controller  is

```
def userDirections
  if user_signed_in?
    redirect_to admin_user_path(admin_user_url)
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

Comment: What's `admin_user_url`?

Comment: @MarekLipka its actually url (I was doing it in wrong way ) 
below answer by #Hussain  worked

Comment: @MarekLipka thanks for your concern :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work

```
def userDirections
  if user_signed_in?
    redirect_to admin_user_path(current_user)
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
end
```